# Foreground image in Panorama App

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on Panorama App for Windows Phone 8 and I have to add Foreground image with the background image.I have successfully added the background image but i don't know how to add foreground image in the same layout.Please help.

```
<phone:Panorama Title="My_app">
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/My_app;component/Assets/texture.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>
```

Using this code i am adding background image but don't know how to add foreground image.

I want to add image in the place of title "My_App" .

Comment: Any sample code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried in simple way like as we add the images in simple windows phone app.

Comment: @NeilTurner - Can you tell me how can we add the foreground images in panorama app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an image instead of a text as title on a panorama control, just add a style to the panorama with a custom title template. For example you can do this by adding the following to the xaml of the page containing the panorama (note: the dots represent any other code):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage> 
...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    ...
    <Style TargetType="phone:Panorama" >
        <Setter Property="TitleTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="Assets/logo.png" Stretch="None" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, add a PanoromaItem, then add an image to that item:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem>
  <Grid>
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" />
  </Grid>
<phone:PanoramaItem>
```